# Query execution time and explain output do not align

Tags: mysql, optimization

I've following query

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN a.*
  FROM b
  INNER JOIN a ON a.b_id = b.b_id
  INNER JOIN c ON dd.a_id = a.id
  WHERE a.a_type_id = 164
    AND a.status = 1
    AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT a2.*
      FROM a a2
      INNER JOIN c c2 ON c2.a_id = a2.id
      INNER JOIN d d.a_id = a2.id
      WHERE a.w_id = 567
        AND c.ds_id = c2.ds_id
    )
  order by b.id
  LIMIT 1;
```

Explain gives following results

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             id: 1
    select_type: PRIMARY
          table: b
           type: index
  possible_keys: index_b_on_b_id
            key: PRIMARY
        key_len: 4
            ref: NULL
           rows: 1
          Extra: 
  *************************** 2. row ***************************
             id: 1
    select_type: PRIMARY
          table: a
           type: ref
  possible_keys: PRIMARY,index_a_on_a_type_id,index_a_on_status,index_a_on_b_id,index_a_on_a_type_id_and_status
            key: index_a_on_b_id
        key_len: 4
            ref: b.b_id
           rows: 1
          Extra: Using where
  *************************** 3. row ***************************
             id: 1
    select_type: PRIMARY
          table: c
           type: ref
  possible_keys: index_c_on_a_id
            key: index_c_on_a_id
        key_len: 4
            ref: a.id
           rows: 1
          Extra: Using where
  *************************** 4. row ***************************
             id: 2
    select_type: DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
          table: c2
           type: ref
  possible_keys: index_c_on_ds_id,index_c_on_a_id
            key: index_c_on_ds_id
        key_len: 4
            ref: c.ds_id
           rows: 1
          Extra: 
  *************************** 5. row ***************************
             id: 2
    select_type: DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
          table: d
           type: ref
  possible_keys: index_d_on_a_id,index_d_on_w_id
            key: index_d_on_a_id
        key_len: 5
            ref: c2.a_id
           rows: 1
          Extra: Using where
  *************************** 6. row ***************************
             id: 2
    select_type: DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
          table: a2
           type: eq_ref
  possible_keys: PRIMARY
            key: PRIMARY
        key_len: 4
            ref: d.a_id
           rows: 1
          Extra: Using where; Using index
```

From explain result, the rows to be scanned is only one but the actual execution time is more than a second. I know Explain is just an estimation and actual execution may vary but is there something that can be optimized here(add new index, rewrite query,etc)?

The number of rows in the tables are as follows:

- a => 2585530
- b => 10000
- c => 2585525
- d => 3350381

Comment: if you remove your "limit 1" how many rows are being evaluated?

Comment: @Steve, removing "limit 1" shows 20373 rows.

Comment: thanks, I will write a generic answer. I don't suppose you're a MySQL Enterprise customer are you?

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to answer questions like these without knowing all the information (schema, data and final goals) but I will try to give some input in a generic way.

You’re evaluating 20,373 rows in your query and only returning one of them, this on the surface seems like a lot of discarded data so might be worth looking into.
Reading your query is almost impossible to identify exactly what you’re trying to do (without all the other information I’ve already noted) – however I can get a reasonable idea of what’s going on here.

I would suggest you look at trying to refactor away the “NOT EXISTS ( … )” element of the query, and instead select the valid data first using conditional statements with an appropriate index, then joining the rest of the data to this first query.

This may not be entirely possible with your data structure, but from what’s provided it’s all I can really recommend. If this isn’t suitable could you edit your answer with more information or an example structure including full schema, sample data and what the final query should output.